# Combining characters using their hexa name

Tags: unicode, raku

This works:

```
say "\c[COMBINING BREVE, COMBINING DOT ABOVE]"  # OUTPUT: «̆̇␤»
```

However, this does not:

```
say "\c[0306, 0307]"; # OUTPUT: «Ĳĳ␤»
```

It's treating it as two different characters. Is there a way to make it work directly by using the numbers, other than use `uniname` to convert it to names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\c[…]` escape is for declaring a character by its name or an alias.
`0306` is not a name, it is the ordinal/codepoint of a character.

The `\x[…]` escape is for declaring a character by its hexadecimal ordinal.

```
say "\x[0306, 0307]"; # OUTPUT: «̆̇␤»
```

(Hint: There is an `x` in a hexadecimal literal `0x0306`)

Comment: \c works with decimal numbers: `say "\c[774]"` is correct, for instance.

Answer (score 5):

\c uses decimal numbers:

```
say "\c[774, 775]"
```

where 774 is the decimal equivalent of 0306, works perfectly.